# D3 map, 'd' attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

(sorry for my english bad level)
Hi I'm using D3 for the first time with mithril js. The map is ok but I have a problem with colors of provinces and it comes from the 'd' attribute to get the id of provinces.The attribute is undefined and I don't understand what is 'd' exactly. is mithril the problem? is there an other way to get 'd' attribute?

```
controller.map = function(el){
    var width = 1160;
    var height = 960;
    var scale = 10000;
    var offset = [width / 2, height / 2];
    var center = [0, 50.64];
    var rotate = [-4.668, 0];
    var parallels = [51.74, 49.34];

    var projection = d3.geo.albers()
        .center(center)
        .rotate(rotate)
        .parallels(parallels)
        .scale(scale)
        .translate(offset)
    ;
    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection)
    ;
    var svg = d3.select(el).append("svg")
        .attr("width",width)
        .attr("height",height)
    ;
    d3.json("belprov.json",function(error,be){
        if (error) return console.error(error);

        var bounds  = path.bounds(topojson.feature(be, be.objects.subunits));
        var hscale  = scale*width  / (bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0]);
        var vscale  = scale*height / (bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1]);
        scale   = (hscale < vscale) ? hscale : vscale;
        offset  = [width - (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0])/2,
            height - (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1])/2];
        var centroid = d3.geo.centroid(topojson.feature(be, be.objects.subunits));
        center = [0, centroid[1]];
        rotate = [-centroid[0],0];
        projection = d3.geo.albers()
            .center(center)
            .rotate(rotate)
            .parallels(parallels)
            .scale(scale)
            .translate(offset);

        svg.selectAll(".province")
            .data(topojson.feature(be, be.objects.provinces).features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "province " + d.id })
            .attr("d", path)
        ;
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to color diffrent paths:

```
//make a color scale
var color20 = d3.scale.category20();
//your code as you doing


//on making paths do 
svg.selectAll(".province")
            .data(topojson.feature(be, be.objects.provinces).features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "province " + d.id })
            .style("fill", function(d){return color(d.id);})//do this to color path based on id.
            .attr("d", path)
```

Answer (score 6):

The `"d"` attribute in a path object defines the successive coordinates of the points through which the path has to go (it also gives indication about whether the path should use bezier curves, straight lines, etc.). See [some documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).

Be careful: in d3, `d` is often used as a parameter for anonymous functions representing the data currently binded to the current element. So the two are completely different things.

Here, your line

```
.attr("d", path)
```

should probably look more like

```
.attr("d", function(d){return d.path})
```

i.e., take the field `path` within the data elements.

Comment: thanks for your response but `.attr("d",path)` works good  and the map is displayed the problem comes from the previous  line  `.attr("class", function(d) { return "province " + d.id })`. With yours changes the problem is the same "d" is undefined and the map is not displayed

Comment: @Minuitdix Ok, sorry I got confused, since "attribute" is normally used for properties of html elements. Here you want to know about the `d` *parameter* of d3's function. A very easy way to know what it looks like is to `console.log(d)` within `.attr("class", function(d) {...})`. It's hard to predict what you'll get there without knowing your original data.

Comment: ok I think that the problem comes from my data there is not id properties in `d` parameter